# Storing Date fetched from datepicker dialog in database?

Tags: android, sqlite, datepicker, android-dialog

I know how to fetch date using datepicker dialog.But, the problem i'm encountering is storing the date picked from date picker dialog into database of type DATE.Since the date fetched from datepicker dialog is not in predefined date format, can anyone help me in converting the date fetched from datepicker into a suitable dateformat ?

Can you also help me about how to proceed fetching the stored date from database and displaying it in datepicker dialog ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Calendar`. Implement your `OnDateChangedListener` method like this:

```
void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth){
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();        
     calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
     calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
     calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

     Date pickedDate = calendar.getTime();
 }
```

Comment: `calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);` or `calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear+1);`(since monthOfYear is 0 based) ?

Comment: As in my answer. Calendar and OnDateChangeListener use zero based month constants.